# How to solve symbolically the following 2nd order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

$\ddot{x}_1(t)+b_1x_1(t)-b_2x_2(t)=f_1(t)$

$\ddot{x}_2(t)+b_3x_2(t)-b_4x_1(t)=f_2(t)$

where $b_i$ are constants for $i=1,2,3,4$ and $f_1(t),f_2(t)$ are unknown time functions. (I will find optimal values for $f_1(t),f_2(t)$ in the next step)

Initial conditions:
$${x}_1(0)=x^{0}_1, {x}_2(0)=x^{0}_2$$

How to find symbolically the solutions ${x}_1(t), 
{x}_2(t)$ in Mathematica ? I am quietly new for solving this question.

Comment: You should try `DSolve`.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a general symbolic answer. And this guess is based on your unknown functions $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$. At example: lets set $f_1(t)=f_2(t)=0$ with following mathematica code: `DSolve[{
x1''[t]+b1*x1[t]-b2*x2[t]==0,
x2''[t]+b3*x2[t]-b4*x1[t]==0
},{x1[t],x2[t]},t]` we get a result which is symbolic but already huge. It would really much help if you specify all your variables and functions. Also your $b_{1,2,3,4}$ . But I would say, you are better situated if you numerically solve for your optimal values.